# Solr query results are all lowercase, but I want the original case

Tags: solr

I implemented an autocomplete feature in solr. The results are always completely lower case where I want them to have the original case. For the query "Alexander" I get the result "alexander", it should be "Alexander"

managed-schema:

```
<field name="suggest_field" type="text_shingle" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
...
<copyField source="_text_" dest="suggest_field"/>
...
    <fieldType name="text_shingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" format="snowball" />
           <!--filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15"/-->
           <!--filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" fillerToken=""/-->
           <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer>
             <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
             <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
    <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
      <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">default</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">suggest_field</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
        <str name="minPrefixChars">2</str>
        <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str> 
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
        <str name="highlight">false</str>
      </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">default</str>        
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      </lst>
      <arr name="components">
         <str>suggest</str>
      </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

When I remove the LowerCaseFilterFactory, I get the original case in the result as required, but then the query is case sensitive. For "alexander" I get 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the LowerCaseFilterFactory only in the index-analyzer seems to do the trick.